# How to solve this memory leak inside a block?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have the following function:

```c
STUDENT *getStudents(size_t *numOfStudents){
  STUDENT *students=malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
  if(students==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not allocate memory. Aborting...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  FILE *data=fopen("in/data.txt","r");
  for(register size_t i=0;fscanf(data,"%"SCNd32" %"SCNd8,&students[i].num,&students[i].finalGrade)==2;i++){
    ++(*numOfStudents);
    {
      STUDENT *sTemp=realloc(students,*numOfStudents*sizeof(STUDENT));
      if(sTemp==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not allocate memory. Aborting...\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
      students=sTemp;
    }
  }
  --(*numOfStudents);
  {
    STUDENT *sTemp=realloc(students,*numOfStudents*sizeof(STUDENT));
    if(sTemp==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Could not allocate memory. Aborting...\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    students=sTemp;
  }
  return students;
}
```

Compiling with `-fsanitize=address`, it detects memory leaks

> in getStudents src/student.c:27

which is the following line:

`STUDENT *sTemp=realloc(students,*numOfStudents*sizeof(STUDENT));`

I thought it would release the memory automatically, because it's inside a block. Even after trying to free it, the same problem happens.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

```
int main(void){
  size_t numOfStudents=1;
  STUDENT *students=getStudents(&numOfStudents);
  printStudents(students,numOfStudents);
  printf("\n================\nMean: %f\n================\n\n",
    (float)getGradeSum(students,numOfStudents)/numOfStudents
  );
  students=removeFailed(students,&numOfStudents);
  printStudents(students,numOfStudents);
  getGradeSum(students,numOfStudents);
  free(students);
  return 0;
}
```

```
int32_t getGradeSum(STUDENT *students,size_t numOfStudents){
  if(numOfStudents==1){
    return students[0].finalGrade;
  }
  else{
    return students[numOfStudents-1].finalGrade+getGradeSum(students,numOfStudents-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just telling you where leaked memory was allocated.  You need to free it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Your usage of `realloc` is correct. The only thing I see is that you call `exit` without freeing `students` before. And it is unclear if the caller of `getStudents` frees the memory that `getStudents` returns.

Comment: @WernerHenze I added a line to free the pointer `students` inside the if of the `realloc`. still the same message from the compiler

Comment: @Duarte: that won't make any difference because that `if` statement never actually executes (as you know, because the message it prints never appears). Technically, you should `free` the memory inside the conditional in case it does happen. But that's not your immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory pointed to by `students` were freed automatically (but it isn't because there is no such thing in C), then you wouldn't be able to `return students` since you would be returning a dangling pointer.

What your function does is dynamically allocate an array of the correct size and return it to the caller. That makes it the caller's responsibility to call `free()`.

Valgrind is just telling you that `free()` was never called on that memory.

---

Now that more of your program (but not all of it) is available, my guess is that the culprit is effectively this line:

```
students=removeFailed(students,&numOfStudents);
```

Presumably, `removeFailed` returns a different pointer than it is given, because it makes a copy of (part of) the array it is being passed. Since it won't free the pointer it is passed as an argument, that allocation is still present. However, since you've replaced the value of `students` (in `main`) with the address of the copy of the array, you can no longer free that memory from `main`. So that's a definite memory leak.

Comment: I thought it was referring to the pointer `sTemp`. Even if that's the case, I just call that function on main to a pointer (also called students). At the end of main, just before returning 0, I have the following line: `free(students);`, so I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: @Duarte: You're confusing the name of a variable with its contents. You need to think about pointers as just simple datatypes, like integers. If you write `a = 4` and then `b = a`, the end result is that both `a` and `b` have the value 4, independently of each other. Pointers are exactly the same. If you set `stemp` to *<some address>* and then do `students = stemp`, then `students` and `stemp` have the same value afterwards. This has nothing to do at all with the memory that is being pointed at.

Comment: Without seeing your `main`, it's impossible to help you with debugging it.

Comment: Just added `main`

Comment: Also added the `getGradeSum` function, as If I remove it, the problem disappears.

Comment: That was it (in the edit). I added a second variable to hold the new returned address and then freed them both. Would there by any better way to do it without creating a second variable? @rici

Comment: @duarte: nope. If you dynamically allocate two objects, you need two free's.